# Assigning multiple environments

Tags: r

Can someone explain this behaviour to me?

```
a <- b <- c <- new.env()
a$this <- 1
b$this 
# 1
c$this 
# 1
```

I would have expected that a/b/c would be distinct environments much like a variable created in the same manner?

However, three environments show in the global environment, but any action on one is pushed into all of them.

Comment: For a nice explanation of the reference semantics of environments see Hadley http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html. --> "As well as powering scoping, environments are also useful data structures in their own right because they have reference semantics. Unlike most objects in R, when you modify an environment, it does not make a copy."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Disclaimer: This answer may not be totally SFW as S-Expressions which is the common type for near all objects in R are abbreviated SEXP (Yep, S-EXPression, the hyphen is not where you thought). Now as [SALT 'N' PEPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Talk_About_Sex) had sing: let's talk about SEXP !

---

TL;DR: An environment is stored in it's parent environment as a pointer, copying the variable to access it, just duplicate the pointer and still target the same object.

---

I did some digging on the root cause, main reason is what is an Environment, or in fact, how it is stored in it's parent environment. Let's see `new.env`:

```
> new.env
function (hash = TRUE, parent = parent.frame(), size = 29L) 
.Internal(new.env(hash, parent, size))
<bytecode: 0x0000000005972428>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Ok, time to go to source code, in [`names.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d6dcebfd84b4ef33a1ab6099fa16b94913296d20/src/main/names.c#L748):

```
{"new.env", do_newenv,  0,  11,     3,      {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
```

Searching `do_newenv` bring us to [`builtin.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/30831f44c07065ad905243679d034f97eafd3e17/src/main/builtin.c#L317) which return (I took a shortcut here, but let's keep this not too long):

```
ans = NewEnvironment(R_NilValue, R_NilValue, enclos);
```

This `NewEnvironment` is defined [here in `memory.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/a549743984a1bcd1c7c9c00a7ddfe9cea6c9a206/src/main/memory.c#L2297) and the comments above it give us a clue about what is going on:

> Create an environment by extending "rho" with a frame obtained by
>   pairing the variable names given by the tags on "namelist" with   the
>   values given by the elements of "valuelist".

The code on itself is not so easy to follow:

```
SEXP NewEnvironment(SEXP namelist, SEXP valuelist, SEXP rho)
{
    SEXP v, n, newrho;

    if (FORCE_GC || NO_FREE_NODES()) {
    PROTECT(namelist);
    PROTECT(valuelist);
    PROTECT(rho);
    R_gc_internal(0);
    UNPROTECT(3);
    if (NO_FREE_NODES())
        mem_err_cons();
    }
    GET_FREE_NODE(newrho);
    newrho->sxpinfo = UnmarkedNodeTemplate.sxpinfo;
    INIT_REFCNT(newrho);
    TYPEOF(newrho) = ENVSXP;
    FRAME(newrho) = valuelist;
    ENCLOS(newrho) = CHK(rho);
    HASHTAB(newrho) = R_NilValue;
    ATTRIB(newrho) = R_NilValue;

    v = CHK(valuelist);
    n = CHK(namelist);
    while (v != R_NilValue && n != R_NilValue) {
    SET_TAG(v, TAG(n));
    v = CDR(v);
    n = CDR(n);
    }
    return (newrho);
}
```

Compared to a variable definition in global environment (exemple choosen for sanity of reader's mind) by [`gsetVar`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/8efa2021dd2a58b53bc1d84a1b013023134bdf98/src/main/envir.c#L1710):

```
void gsetVar(SEXP symbol, SEXP value, SEXP rho)
{
    if (FRAME_IS_LOCKED(rho)) {
    if(SYMVALUE(symbol) == R_UnboundValue)
        error(_("cannot add binding of '%s' to the base environment"),
          CHAR(PRINTNAME(symbol)));
    }
#ifdef USE_GLOBAL_CACHE
    R_FlushGlobalCache(symbol);
#endif
    SET_SYMBOL_BINDING_VALUE(symbol, value);
}
```

We can see the "value" accessible from parent environment is the new environment address, given by the `GET_FREE_NODE` on parent environment (I'm unsure I'm clear here, but I didn't find a correct phrasing).

So with the fact `<-` is defined as `x <- value` we're copying a pointer, we have multiples independent variables, all pointing to the same object.

Updating the object using any reference update the only object existing in memory.

`SEXP` stand for S-Expression according to various literrature and is mainly a pointer in C.

From comments,

- [R language defintion](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Environment-objects), thanks @BrodieG
- [A blog post about R's C interface](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html)
- Thanks @Alexis_laz to have enforce me to get the real root cause in a more detailled manner.

Comment: So, if I were to summarize. It's because `new.env()` returns a pointer to an environment and essentially when you chain `a<-b<-c<-new.env()` you're only pushing a pointer to `b` and `c` and therefore all actions taken on one automatically push to the others (because the others are just pointing to the first).

Comment: @Brandon exactly. And new.env documentation does not state it clearly.

Comment: What does *SEXP* stand for? Googling that threw me out of office, nearly.

Comment: IIRC Standard EXtended Pointer, heading home, I'll confirm tomorow and will add to the answer.

Comment: @BhargavRao brilliant. Programming in C, not safe for work.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I am about to edit Tensibai's answer to add a banner stating that it is NSFW.

Comment: I think this behavior has more to do with the fact that `"$<-"` does not duplicate an "environent" in contrast to other objects. For example `a = b = list()` seem, also, to be the same "SEXP" before calling `"$<-"`: `a = b = list(); .Internal(inspect(a)); .Internal(inspect(b)); b$this = 1; .Internal(inspect(a)); .Internal(inspect(b))`

Comment: @Alexis to be exact, it is how the world 'v object define it's getter compared to how a list define it, but I'm afraid this answer would become too long if I enter into this detail, main idea was explaining the access by reference instead of acces by value. But you're right. I'll see if I can extend the answer on it tomorow.

Comment: So after a quick Googling (absolutely safe for Work :p) I found [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html) which gives a good insight of What SEXP are. I've to review this answer as it takes more shortcut than I though at first (not now, typing on phone is a pain)

Comment: Fyi, the canonical reference for this is **[section 2.1.10 of the R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Environment-objects)**

Comment: thanks @Brodie, didn't find this while searching a doc about envs :)

Comment: I was surprised when I checked; I then remembered about the above manual from having read it a couple of years ago.  Worthwhile read.  Btw, looks like you're getting deep into the R internals.

Comment: @BrodieG indeed I love understanding this kind of problems, I'm not a daily R user but it's always interesting to analyse and learn from how first-class coders did something ;)

Comment: @Tensibai : I agree with the refenrece copying; I was mostly commenting on `NewEnvironment` (it's not the only function that returns a SEXP pointer) and on `"<-"` which, generally, does not copy. It's the "setter" (`"$<-"` etc.) that does the actual copying (if needed) when modifying the object and in case of "ENVSXP"s, by definition, it does not. Not only for "list"s, before subassigning takes place, many objects refer to the same pointer (`a = b = 1; .Internal(inspect(a)); .Internal(inspect(b)); b[1] = 0; .Internal(inspect(a)); .Internal(inspect(b))`).

Comment: @Alexis yes. Typical copy on write behavior, I agree I took too much shortcuts in the explanation, I'll review the copy tomorow in a most accurate way.

Answer (score 7):

`new.env()` is only being called once though, creating only one new environment.  They all get the same environment because you chained all of the assignments to the same `new.env()` call.  Therefore, when you assign to one you assign to them all.

```
a <- b <- c <- new.env()

a
# <environment: 0x49c1ed8>
b
# <environment: 0x49c1ed8>
c
# <environment: 0x49c1ed8>
```

If you want them to be separate environments, don't chain the assignment (i.e. use three separate calls to `new.env()`).

For completeness, bringing Tensibai's comment in -

> this is a side effect of `<-` your line of code is the same as `a <- new.env(); b <- a; c <- a` (which more obvisouly does not call `new.env()` 3 times, but reference it to 3 variables names)

Comment: Can you think of a good reason for 3 copies of the same environment in one workspace? I'd be interested in understanding a use case for this behaviour. My understanding was that environments are designed to be like `lists()`, but this behaviour is a bit unintuitive and unexpected.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen this is a side effect of `<-` your line of code is the same as `a <- new.env(); b <- a; c <- a` (which more obvisouly does not call new.env() 3 times, but reference it to 3 variables names)

Comment: As stated above, I think this has more to do with assignment.  `a <- b <- c <- 3` would definitely be useful in some cases, but obviously would not really be useful with environments.

Comment: Could you integrate @Tensibai 's comment in your answer. I think that's the "other half" of the explanation.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen - Sorry, I am not well versed in C. Glad you got your question answered. :)

Comment: No worries, my understanding of a pointer goes back to 2001, when I took a course in Structured C. I feel your pain.